# "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" error on deployment

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting this error when I deploy a VB.NET application and for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

I do not get this error when I run the app from the IDE and the test machine I am deploying it to has a similar configuration to the dev machine...Windows 7 & .NET 3.51 SP1 and 4.0.

The app bombs out when the main form is loaded after logging in.  I've narrowed it down to the main form because if I load another form from login and then open the main form, this happens.

Linked below is a screenshot of the stack trace.

Any ideas?  I'm really lost here.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a way for ShapeCollection.Dispose() to throw that exception.  Although it is manipulating a List<> that can indeed throw that exception, the code should not trigger it:

```
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!this.m_Disposed && disposing)
    {
        for (int i = this.m_Shapes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            this.m_Shapes[i].Dispose();
        }
        this.m_Shapes.Clear();
        this.m_Shapes = null;
    }
    this.m_Disposed = true;
}
```

Well, this is from the PowerPacks version that I have.  There have been a couple of versions of it floating around, it used to be distributed separately.  Make sure you didn't accidentally deploy an old version.

Comment: Oh hey Hans.  You think it's the PowerPacks that is causing this error?

Comment: It was the PowerPacks.  I have rectangle shapes on some of my forms and when I removed them and the reference to the PowerPacks the app runs fine.  Very annoyed that something so simple like a shape could mess things up so much and that I have to change the design of the app to get around this but whatever, time is of the essence and I don't want to waste anymore time on lines and rectangles.