# System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute when form closes

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error

## **I fixed this issue by removing the line shapes from the form.**

## Original Post

When my form closes I get the following error:

> > System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

This only appears when the program is deployed on a machine not during debug. If I hide the form it doesn't occur only when the form is closed.

Any help is greatly appreciated as this is becoming really annoying now.
Thanks in advance,
Craig

p.s. Below is the FormClosed event

```
    'Disconnect from database
    cn.Close()
    cn.Dispose()
```

#### Stack Trace

```
   ************** Exception Text **************
   System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeCollection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at EquiManager.frmEditJumpingShow.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: You must post at least the stack trace of the exception to get help with this.

Comment: This question is already in other post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788919/exception-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute-on-fo

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751858/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute-error-on-deploy

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I have added the Stack Trace.

Comment: Surely you've seen the link Pushpendra posted?  It is the same problem.

Comment: @HansPassant So should I do something like the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the line shapes and the error disappeared.